# Using Eclipse Decorators without plugin.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I currently have a plugin that defines some decorators using the plugin.xml extension point. However, I understand that Eclipse is moving away from the plugin.xml paradigm in newer releases. I want to convert my plugin to be as future-facing as possible, so I'd like to separate the decorators from plugin.xml. However, I can't find any information on using decorators outside of plugin.xml. Any tips or pointers?

Comment: Eclipse is not moving away from plugin.xml

Comment: Oh. I guess I misunderstood...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator manager `org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager` only supports decorations defined by extension points in the plugin.xml.

Although Eclipse e4 uses the application model rather than plugin.xml extension points to define the user interface this does not mean that the extension point mechanism is being abandoned.